# Get value from JSON response in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I am making a JSON call to a Ruby on Rails server via a client side ruby script, which returns the following JSON:

**get_data.rb**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def get_functions(serial_number, function)
  request_uri = "http://localhost:3000/devices/#{serial_number}"
  buffer = open(request_uri).read
  result = JSON.parse(buffer)
  puts result
end
```

```
{ "serial_number" => "111aaa",
  "device_functions" => [
    { "can_scan" => true,
      "can_halt" => true
    }
  ],
  "host_options" => [
    { "exclude_ip" => "10.10.10.100-110",
      "scan_ip" => "10.10.10.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I'm wanting to just extract certain values from the response to determine what can/cannot be done on the client side:

**scan.rb**

```
if get_functions('111aaa', 'can_scan')
  result = %x( ping 10.10.10.1 )
else
  result = "Not allowed to perform action!"
end
```

I'm stuck with how I can extract the value of `can_scan` from my JSON in **get_data.rb** for my `get_functions` method to be able to run its `if` statement correctly.

Comment: @Pavan that throws an error:  ``get_functions': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from scan.rb:3:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `get_functions` is returning `nil` as the last line is an I/O operation (`puts`). Change your function to:

```
def get_functions(serial_number, function)
  request_uri = "http://localhost:3000/devices/#{serial_number}"
  buffer = open(request_uri).read
  result = JSON.parse(buffer)
  puts result
  result
end
```

And access the Hash:

```
result = get_functions(serial_number, function)
result["device_functions"].first["can_scan"]
```

Comment: How do you propose doing that since I need to pass the `serial_number` and `function` to the `get_functions` method to get the JSON?

Comment: sorry, missed that...I updated my answer, just put the result in a variable (more readable).

Comment: So, now I get: `scan.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: just updated the answer again, the hash keys are strings.